# Are element added by .append() already ready after appended?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am building a kind of infinite scroll with jquery, but I am facing a DOM ready problem.

```
var n = 0;

// When user wants to load more, call this 
function load_10_images(){

    var g; var images = '';

    for(g=1; g<=10; g++){

        // Create images
        images = '<div id="'+n+'" >'+
                    '<li id="li'+n+'">'+
                        '<img id="img'+n+'" src="images/loading.gif" />'+
                    '</li>'+
                 '</div>';

        // add to html
        $("#list").append(images);

        // change source
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "data.php",
            data: {link_n: n},
            success: function(resp) {
                $("#img"+n).attr("src", resp);
            },
        });

        // ...
        n++;
    }

}
```

My problem is images sources don't change. How to solve this problem ?

Comment: `var n = g;` inside your loop?

Comment: I checked the response with alert(), and it gives me the wanted link ('http://example.com/images/1.png'), so the problem is not from my php file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript closure inside loops - simple practical example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that since AJAX is async, your variable `n` inside the success call is equal to the variable `n` inside the last loop. Add a closure like that :

```
(function(int){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "data.php",
        data: {link_n: int},
        success: function(resp) {
            $("#img"+int).attr("src", resp);
        },
    });
})(n);
```

Comment: +1 for actually providing an answer, not just describing the problem.

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is scope.  You create the DIVs and IMG ids with n as you loop through it.  But you access the value of n in your ajax callback.  So it will attempt to find $("#img"+n).attr("src", resp); with whatever the current value of n is (most likely the final value since it will finish faster than the post returns);

Comment: ok, problem solved. I didn't noticed that. I used @Karl-André Gagnon 's  script

Answer (score 0):

As many people have pointed out, you have other issues that are causing the problems that you are seeing, but to answer your actual question, yes, they are available after `.append()`.  Actually, what you find people do, frequently, is actually make the element available *before* appending it.  In your code (since you're using jQuery), you could do that like this:

```
images = $('<div id="'+n+'" >'+
    '<li id="li'+n+'">'+
        '<img id="img'+n+'" src="images/loading.gif" />'+
    '</li>'+
'</div>');
```

At that point, the element exists and can be read, modified, etc., but simply has not been added to the DOM yet.